# Sum functions doesn't show total values in single row after grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to showcase the total hours worked for each employee that worked on different dates.

I can use group by and sum function but I have multiple columns to showcase and it gives the same result sum with multiple rows. Additionally, I don't want to write every column name in group by clause as its not proper way of query writing.

I managed to get employees working hours from different tables using joins but couldn't sum up them in single row as a record. However it shows sum in multiple rows.

The script I used to get all the data is given below:

```
Select e.employeecode, Isnull(e.PreferredName,e.FirstNames) + '
    ' + e.LastName as [Name], w.Position
    , sum(h.TotalHours) over (partition by e.employeecode order by e.employeecode)[TotalHours]
    , e.Salary, e.startdate    
From employee e
Left join Appointment ap on ap.EmployeeCode = e.EmployeeCode
left join Work w on w.WorkCode = ap.workCode 
left join HistoricalAllowance h on h.EmployeeCode = e.EmployeeCode 
left join TransPerPaySequence TP on tp.PaySequence = h.PaySequence
Where tp.PeriodEnd between '2021-04-24' and '2021-05-07'
and h.AllowanceCode in ('99','1000') and
and ap.isactive ='1'
group by e.EmployeeCode
```

It looks right now after writing a script:

| employeecode | Name | Position | **TotalHours** | Salary | StartDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Anna | employee-Com | 63.45 | 500 | 40792 |
| 1234 | Anna | employee-Com | 486.45 | 500 | 40792 |
| 2345 | Jacky | Manager | 126.9 | 700 | 41395 |
| 2345 | Jacky | Manager | 961.05 | 700 | 41395 |
| 2345 | Jacky | Manager | 67.05 | 700 | 41395 |
| 3456 | Mahato | HR | 402.3 | 570 | 41933 |
| 3456 | Mahato | HR | 67.05 | 570 | 41933 |
| 3456 | Mahato | HR | 126.9 | 570 | 41933 |
| 3456 | Mahato | HR | 126.9 | 570 | 41933 |

The way I wanted

| employeecode | Name | Position | **TotalHours** | Salary | StartDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Anna | employee-Com | **549.9** | 500 | 40792 |
| 2345 | Jacky | Manager | **1155** | 700 | 41395 |
| 3456 | Mahato | HR | **723.15** | 570 | 41933 |

Please help and let me know what I am missing.

Thanks In advance

Comment: *I don't want to write every column name in group by clause as its not proper way of query writing.* - you cannot effectively code if you make up such rules, which are not necessarily true

Comment: *Additionally, I don't want to write every column name in group by clause as its not proper way of query writing.* on the contrary its very much the correct way of writing a `group by` query. Also you have a double and `and and` in your query, so it definitely doesn't even run as stated.

Comment: Remove the partition by will solve this. I will add the complete solution for you

Comment: I note that the left joins on `Appointment` `HistoricalAllowance` and `TransPerPaySequence` are effectively inner joins, due to the `where` clauses, they should probably be in the `on`

Comment: Unlike MySQL, MS SQL Server doesn't support the ANSI SQL 1999 `group by` syntax. If you want aggregates, you have to list all other columns in the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can appreciate not wanting to list all the columns for the `GROUP BY` . . . but for a slightly different reason:  If you can avoid the aggregation then the query is likely to be faster.

And SQL Server offers a convenient solution, using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
select e.employeecode,
       coalesce(e.PreferredName, e.FirstNames) + ' ' + e.LastName as Name,
       w.Position,
       h.TotalHoursTotalHours, e.Salary, e.startdate    
From employee e Left join
     Appointment ap
     on ap.EmployeeCode = e.EmployeeCode left join
     Work w
     on w.WorkCode = ap.workCode outer apply
     (select sum(h.TotalHours) as TotalHours
      from HistoricalAllowance h join 
           TransPerPaySequence TP
           on tp.PaySequence = h.PaySequence
      where h.EmployeeCode = e.EmployeeCode and
            tp.PeriodEnd between '2021-04-24' and '2021-05-07' and
            h.AllowanceCode in ('99','1000') 
     ) h
where ap.isactive = '1';
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `OVER(...)` clause and then put every other (non SUMmed) column mentioned in the SELECT, into the GROUP BY also

Adhering to your *it's not proper way of query writing* rule is tripping you up on this one

ps, I've a doubt that the posted query in your question even runs - SQL server is not, to my knowledge, one of the few databases that will allow you to limit group by columns to just those on which all other selected, non aggregated columns are functionally dependent. Your query as posted should give a "column x in the select list is invalid because it is not an aggregate/in the group by" error